# How to not end an Android IntentService when onHandleIntent() finishes?

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking

I start an IntentService.  In onHandleIntent() I make an HTTP request with a Handler that is called when the request completes, like so:

```
public function onHandleIntent(){
    makeRequest("http://somehthing.com", new Handler(){
        doStuff();
    });
}
```

onHandleIntent() finishes immediately, before the HTTP request returns.  The request does return, but the ServiceIntent thread has already been destroyed and doStuff() doesn't ever run.

What is the best way to handle a callback Handler structure like this with a ServiceIntent?

Comment: Where is doStuff() declared? Something doesn't seem right about this handler. Did you mean something like new Handler() { int doStuff() { ... }} ?

Comment: Sorry, doStuff() doesn't really exist.  It is a placeholder to say that the code there never gets executed.

Comment: Can you post the actual code? From this snippet it's not clear how you specify the callback. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't. `IntentService` is meant to queue off synchronous blocks of work, complete them in another thread, then finish. You'll have to create your own Service. You can take a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/IntentService.java) for `IntentService` and start from there. Most importantly, you'll want to call `stopSelf` after the callback is completed instead of after `onHandleIntent`.